# Query with overlapping date range

Tags: sql

I created a report where in an ID is selected by the user. Under that ID there is a cut off  period and within that ID it is split into one or more records that have date range also.
For example:

```
   ID: MMA1512 - 3/1-3/15
        compose of
            -- > 'P2306.2012.15.03.A.STAFF' - 2/24-3/8
            -- > 'P2306.2012.08.03.A.DAILY' - 3/1-3/15

  Tables:
     Work Allocation 
       id
   startdate

     Work Allocation Details
        workallocationid
        employee no
        costcode
        subcostcode
        hrswork
```

The problem is there is an overlapping data for 3/1-3/8 but I cannot exclude the overlapping date because it was needed on 'P2306.2012.08.03.A.DAILY'. Here is my query

**Wrong Output**

```
 SELECT wa.companycode,wa.sitecode,wa_details.employeeno,    
        wa_details.costcode,wa_details.subcostcode,  
   SUM(wa_details.hrswork) hrswork,ttl_work_hrs  
FROM WorkAllocation wa  
INNER JOIN WorkAllocation_details wa_details  ON wa.id = wa_details.workallocationid  
INNER JOIN              
(  SELECT employee_id,ttl_work_hrs FROM [dbo].[Get_Total_Work_Hours]  ('mma1512','P2306.2012.15.03.l.STAFF,P2306.2012.08.03.l.DAILY','p2306','l'))                
 view_ttl_hours 
 ON 
wa_details.employeeno=view_ttl_hours.employee_id  
 WHERE 
companycode='l'
 AND 
sitecode='p2306' 
 AND 
startdate BETWEEN '2012-02-24' AND '2012-03-15'
 GROUP BY wa.companycode,wa.sitecode,       wa_details.employeeno,wa_details.costcode,wa_details.subcostcode,ttl_work_hrs   

     Company Site   EmployeeNo CostCode SubCostCode HrsWork Total Hours Work
      LCPI   P2306  PH080323    8321    169        160.50   162.5
      LCPI   P2306  PH080323    10184   2648       14.50    162.5
```

**Correct Output**

```
SELECT wa.companycode,wa.sitecode,wa_details.employeeno,    
        wa_details.costcode,wa_details.subcostcode,  
   SUM(wa_details.hrswork) hrswork,ttl_work_hrs  
FROM WorkAllocation wa  
INNER JOIN WorkAllocation_details wa_details  ON wa.id = wa_details.workallocationid  
INNER JOIN              
(  SELECT employee_id,ttl_work_hrs FROM [dbo].[Get_Total_Work_Hours]  ('mma1512','P2306.2012.15.03.l.STAFF,P2306.2012.08.03.l.DAILY','p2306','l'))                
 view_ttl_hours 
 ON 
wa_details.employeeno=view_ttl_hours.employee_id  
 WHERE 
companycode='l'
 AND 
sitecode='p2306' 
 AND 
startdate BETWEEN '2012-02-24' AND '2012-03-08'
 GROUP BY wa.companycode,wa.sitecode,       wa_details.employeeno,wa_details.costcode,wa_details.subcostcode,ttl_work_hrs

   Company Site   EmployeeNo CostCode SubCostCode HrsWork Total Hours Work
      LCPI    P2306  PH080323   8321    169    148.00   162.5
      LCPI    P2306  PH080323   10184   2648       14.50    162.5
```

The difference between the query is the **startdate BETWEEN '2012-02-24' AND '2012-03-15'**

Comment: The only difference between `desired` and `wrong` outputs is `HrsWork` yet you didn't post the code that calculates it ([dbo].[Get_Total_Work_Hours]). Also you mention overlapping dates but we don't get to see them. Please post sample data we can work with.

Comment: Yes the difference is only the value of the HrsWork because on the *wrong output* it includes the overlapping date. I will post the sample data.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović I already edited my post. I hope you will understand it now. Thanks!

Comment: Why did you copy the query? It seems identical to me. On the other hand, I've asked input data and code of Get_total_work_hours because I cannot trust that 162.5 is in fact correct. Perhaps HrsWork shows correct number, and total should be 175? Anyway, please post this employee's records from `WorkAllocation_details`.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović I want to show you that the problem is on the date range. There are two date range underneath the ID MMA1512. please read my above description. The Total Work hours is correct, the only problem is the HrsWork.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović oops sorry. Notice the problem. I will edit my post.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović please take a look again of my post.

Comment: I'm afraid you did not save the changes.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović i saved it. The date range for the **correct output** is '2012-02-24' AND '2012-03-08' while **wrong output** is '2012-02-24' AND '2012-03-15'

Comment: I don't understand why is `[dbo].[Get_Total_Work_Hours]` out of sync with `WorkAllocation_details`. These two should get the same data for the same period but apparently they do not. Date range itself should not be the problem, but the queries inside Get_Total_Work_Hours use different set of data to produce total than this query.

Comment: HrsWork is the sum of the WorkAllocation_Details the Total Work Hours is the sum of the attendance sheet for each employee.

Comment: Are you saying that somebody have worked 12.5 hours between 9th and 15th, but forgot to clock-in the card? How would any query account for discrepancies in linked data?